# Циклические алгоритмы. В чём ошибка? C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, visual-studio

Я сделал программу для табулирования функции y(x) при условиях [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при запуске программы у меня ничего не происходит просто пустое окно  `textBox5.Text`  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чём ошибка? Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace R1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Считывание начальных данных
            double x0 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            double xk = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            double dx = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            double b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text);
            double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text);
            textBox5.Text = "Работу выполнил " +
                Environment.NewLine;
            // Цикл для табулирования функции
            double x = x0;
            while (x <= (xk + dx / 2))
            {
                double y = x * Math.Sin(Math.Sqrt(x + b - a));
                textBox5.Text += "x=" + Convert.ToString(x) + "; y=" + Convert.ToString(y) + Environment.NewLine;
                x = x + dx;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "-2,05";
            textBox2.Text = "-3,05";
            textBox3.Text = "-0,2";
            textBox4.Text = "3,4";
            textBox6.Text = "0,0084";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (x >= (xk + dx / 2))
{
  ...
```